# python subprocess.popen read only whats returned

Tags: python

im faily new to python. need to understand more about subprocess.popen.

i have a script that executes another python script. below is the part where my script will try to execute another script.

```
cmd = ['python %s %s %s %s %s'%(runscript, steps, part_number, serial_number, self.operation)]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
result = p.stdout.readline()
```

the problem is, the script that gets executed, i have to print out the result in order to read results through "result = p.stdout.readline()".  below is the script that gets executed

```
def Main():

if sys.argv[1] == "Initiate" :
    doFunc = Functions_obj.Initiate()
    if doFunc != 0 :
        print doFunc
    else :
        print "Initiate PASS"

elif sys.argv[1] == "Check" :
    getDrive = Functions_obj.initialize()
    if getDrive == "NoDevice" :
        print getDrive
        sys.exit()

    doFunc = Functions_obj.Identify_Drive()
    if doFunc != 0 :
        print doFunc
    else :
        print "Check PASS"
```

my question is, i want to "return" results from the script that gets executed and not print. how do i do this with subprocess.popen? and how do i use subprocess to get whats returned rather than whats printed

Answer (score 0):

You can't return data through a pipe like a function call. You have to use one of the many IPC mechanisms like pipes, shared memory, message passing, or sockets. Pipes are generally the simplest, and that's what you're doing here. You can send binary data through the pipe, though. You could try pickling your data, assuming it's pickleable.